# Adjust axis limit in bar plot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can anyone help me to set the limits of the horizontal axis in the figure to (0,1) please? The code below does not work.

```
set.seed(234)
data <- data.frame(var1 = c(rep('A',3),rep('B',3)),
                   var2 = runif(6), 
                   var3 = rep(c('x1','x2','x3'),2))

ggplot(data,aes(x=var1,y=var2,fill=factor(var3))) + 
   geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + 
   scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,0.5,1.0)) +
   coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1.0)) +
   coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for coord_cartesian(), you can pass the ylim arg into coord_flip() directly.

```
set.seed(234)
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(var1 = c(rep('A',3),rep('B',3)),
               var2 = runif(6), 
               var3 = rep(c('x1','x2','x3'),2))

ggplot(data,aes(x=var1,y=var2,fill=factor(var3))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,0.5,1.0)) +
  coord_flip(ylim = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/coord_flip.html